# Iterator does not remove an especific item form a list

Tags: java, iterator

I'm trying to remove a specific item from a list, but the iterator just don't remove, it prints a message but the item keep in there(on the list). Can someone help me please?

The method:

```
    public void removerItemLista(Material pegarMaterial) {
    Iterator<PegaMaterial> pegaMaterialIterator = materials.iterator();

    while (pegaMaterialIterator.hasNext()){
        if (pegaMaterialIterator.next().equals(pegarMaterial)) {
            pegaMaterialIterator.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Todos os " + pegarMaterial + " foram removidos da lista");
    System.out.println(materials.size());
}
```

If you need some more code please tell me, thanks for the help!!

@Edit: I discovered just now the removeIf from java 8, I've tryed to do this, but doesn't work too:

```
materials.removeIf(material -> material.equals(pegarMaterial));
```

Comment: What type is `materials`?

Comment: Did you correctly implement `Material.equals()`?

Comment: @vonox7 type Material

Comment: @DarknessHunter `materials` is an iterable... So not `Material`

Comment: @LukasEder I hope so ;-;, but when I put my cursor on equals, this appear, " 'equals()' between objects of inconvertible types 'PegaMaterial' and 'Material"

Comment: @YassinHajaj I didn't understood, explain to me please, I'm kinda a newbie on Bukkit API and Java

Comment: Put some logging inside of the if or debug it manually, you'll know for sure it does or does not go into the if

Comment: It seems that PegaMaterial and Material do not share the same inheritance tree?

Comment: @YassinHajaj I just solved the problem removing the PegaMaterial class and doing the list of type Material, I don't know if that was the problem, but, it works

Comment: @YassinHajaj @DarknessHunter Many `equals` implementations will return `false` if the objects are not EXACTLY the same runtime class. (ie if `pegaMaterial` is not an instance of `PegaMaterial`)

Comment: @YassinHajaj Oh, I think I got it, I'll pratice a few lists to stay good on doing that, thanks for the help guys, the problem was solved.